RuntimeError: Broken/missing geospatial data was found in file NetCDF (OpenDataCube)
I'm trying to index and load a time-stacked NetCDF file with OpenDataCube . Product Definition and Dataset.yaml files get from the link: How to index and load a time-stacked NetCDF file with Open Data Cube? . When query with the data get this error :

query = {
    "latitude": (-35.45, -35.44),
    "longitude": (149.0, 149.01),
    "output_crs": "EPSG:4326",
    "resolution": (0.00027778, -0.00027778),
}

data = dc.load(product='mfwamglocep_mini', **query)
print(data)
Error opening source dataset: NETCDF:"/localdata/mfwamglocep_2021013000_R20210122_mini.nc":VHM0


----------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 8
      1 query = {
      2     "latitude": (-35.45, -35.44),
      3     "longitude": (149.0, 149.01),
      4     "output_crs": "EPSG:4326",
      5     "resolution": (0.00027778, -0.00027778),
      6 }
----> 8 data = dc.load(product='mfwamglocep_mini', **query)
      9 print(data)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datacube/api/core.py:456, in Datacube.load(self, product, measurements, output_crs, resolution, resampling, skip_broken_datasets, dask_chunks, like, fuse_func, align, datasets, dataset_predicate, progress_cbk, patch_url, **query)
    452 measurement_dicts = datacube_product.lookup_measurements(measurements)
    454 # `extra_dims` put last for backwards compability, but should really be the second position
    455 # betwween `grouped` and `geobox`
--> 456 result = self.load_data(grouped, geobox,
    457                         measurement_dicts,
    458                         resampling=resampling,
    459                         fuse_func=fuse_func,
    460                         dask_chunks=dask_chunks,
    461                         skip_broken_datasets=skip_broken_datasets,
    462                         progress_cbk=progress_cbk,
    463                         extra_dims=extra_dims,
    464                         patch_url=patch_url)
    466 return result

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datacube/api/core.py:814, in Datacube.load_data(sources, geobox, measurements, resampling, fuse_func, dask_chunks, skip_broken_datasets, progress_cbk, extra_dims, patch_url, **extra)
    809     return Datacube._dask_load(sources, geobox, measurements, dask_chunks,
    810                                skip_broken_datasets=skip_broken_datasets,
    811                                extra_dims=extra_dims,
    812                                patch_url=patch_url)
    813 else:
--> 814     return Datacube._xr_load(sources, geobox, measurements,
    815                              skip_broken_datasets=skip_broken_datasets,
    816                              progress_cbk=progress_cbk,
    817                              extra_dims=extra_dims,
    818                              patch_url=patch_url)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datacube/api/core.py:742, in Datacube._xr_load(sources, geobox, measurements, skip_broken_datasets, progress_cbk, extra_dims, patch_url)
    740 data_slice = data[m.name].values[index]
    741 try:
--> 742     _fuse_measurement(data_slice, datasets, geobox, m,
    743                       skip_broken_datasets=skip_broken_datasets,
    744                       progress_cbk=_cbk, extra_dim_index=extra_dim_index,
    745                       patch_url=patch_url)
    746 except (TerminateCurrentLoad, KeyboardInterrupt):
    747     data.attrs['dc_partial_load'] = True

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datacube/api/core.py:972, in _fuse_measurement(dest, datasets, geobox, measurement, skip_broken_datasets, progress_cbk, extra_dim_index, patch_url)
    969     else:
    970         srcs.append(src)
--> 972 reproject_and_fuse(srcs,
    973                    dest,
    974                    geobox,
    975                    dest.dtype.type(measurement.nodata),
    976                    resampling=measurement.get('resampling_method', 'nearest'),
    977                    fuse_func=measurement.get('fuser', None),
    978                    skip_broken_datasets=skip_broken_datasets,
    979                    progress_cbk=progress_cbk,
    980                    extra_dim_index=extra_dim_index)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datacube/storage/_load.py:77, in reproject_and_fuse(datasources, destination, dst_gbox, dst_nodata, resampling, fuse_func, skip_broken_datasets, progress_cbk, extra_dim_index)
     75 elif len(datasources) == 1:
     76     with ignore_exceptions_if(skip_broken_datasets):
---> 77         with datasources[0].open() as rdr:
     78             read_time_slice(rdr, destination, dst_gbox, resampling, dst_nodata, extra_dim_index)
     80     if progress_cbk:

File /usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py:135, in _GeneratorContextManager.__enter__(self)
    133 del self.args, self.kwds, self.func
    134 try:
--> 135     return next(self.gen)
    136 except StopIteration:
    137     raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datacube/storage/_rio.py:146, in RasterioDataSource.open(self)
    144 except Exception as e:
    145     _LOG.error("Error opening source dataset: %s", self.filename)
--> 146     raise e
    147 finally:
    148     if locked:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datacube/storage/_rio.py:141, in RasterioDataSource.open(self)
    138             lock.release()
    140         if override:
--> 141             raise RuntimeError(f'Broken/missing geospatial data was found in file "{self.filename}"')
    142         yield BandDataSource(band, nodata=nodata, lock=lock)
    144 except Exception as e:

RuntimeError: Broken/missing geospatial data was found in file "NETCDF:"/localdata/mfwamglocep_2021013000_R20210122_mini.nc":VHM0"


You can check if your NetCDF file has the necessary CRS information by using gdalinfo or ncdump:
gdalinfo /localdata/mfwamglocep_2021013000_R20210122_mini.nc

ncdump -h /localdata/mfwamglocep_2021013000_R20210122_mini.nc

If it doesn't, you can write it, e.g., using Python packages xarray and rioxarray:
import xarray

dataset = xarray.open_dataset("/localdata/mfwamglocep_2021013000_R20210122_mini.nc")
dataset.rio.write_crs(4326, inplace=True)
dataset.to_netcdf("/localdata/mfwamglocep_2021013000_R20210122_mini_with_crs.nc")


thank you so much , you made my day , this is a final project for me (as a student) before graduation. once again thank you so much . have a great day sir .

Looking at the source code, this error means one of two things:
a) Rasterio could not extract a spatial transform from the file, or
b) Rasterio could not extract a CRS from the file.

maybe the file dataset.yaml is wrong  , i'm new to opendatacube (cube-in-the-box) ., do you have an example for writing and indexing netcdf data ? Thankyou
